# Как пройтись циклом по значениям словаря

Tags: python, циклы, for

У меня есть функция, которая принимает строку. Также, есть переменная со словарем(откуда мне требуется вырывать значения элементов, которые поступают в функцию. Мне нужно пройтись по ней циклом, чтобы позже добавлять их в переменную и сравнивать значения. Однако, у меня не получается пройтись именно по значениям

```
Roman = {
    'I' : 1,
    'II': 2,
    'III':3,
    'V' : 5,
    'X' : 10,
    'L': 50,
    'C' : 100,
    'D' : 500,
    'M' : 1000  
}

Arabic = []

def RomantoArabic(number):
    for blabla in number:
        for j in blabla.values():
            if j not in Arabic:
                Arabic.append(j)
                print(Arabic) #написал для примера, однако мне нужно будет эти значения
```

сравнивать и тд.

Comment: Вы и так проходитесь по значениям словаря. Опишите что вы конкретно будете сравнивать, и какой должен быть результат?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите в вопрос пример того, что подаётся на вход функции, и что должно быть на выходе

Comment: Спасибо за столь скорые ответы. Дело в том, что у меня также имеется переменная со словарям(я не стал её выклыдывать, так как нет смысла. Я пытаюсь пройтись по значениям, которые приходят в number на вход (это будут римские цифры('XI', 'XCIX')). Эти цифры имеются у меня в словаре, и мне нужно проходится именно по значениям этих ключей, чтобы их сравнивать на больше меньше и так далее, не хочу спрашивать полностью решение парсинга, так как хочу попробовать сделать самостоятельно, но уже столкнулся с проблемой)

Comment: @AzatSamaratov дополните вопрос этими значениями, вы можете нажать [edit] под самим вопросом, для того, чтобы дополнить вопрос